# Convert dynamic text data rows into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to convert my result table which consist of multiple rows into multiple columns. below are my sample result before and after:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Got a some idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630650/pivot-with-varchar-datatype) but still no luck.

**Update 1:**

```
select @cols = STUFF((select ',' + QUOTENAME(institution) + ',' +        QUOTENAME(intstatus)
                From @temp
                group by refno,frmstatus
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

i have no idea how to insert each column into the pivot query

```
set @query = 'select refno, frmstatus,' + @cols + '
from (
     select refno, frmstatus, institution, intstatus from #temp
) x
pivot
(
???????
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(refno nvarchar(20), firmstatus nvarchar(20), institution nvarchar(20), intstatus nvarchar(20), ranking int)
DECLARE @qu NVARCHAR(MAX), @pcol NVARCHAR(MAX)


INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT  
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY refno ORDER BY institution ASC) AS ranking
FROM temp

SELECT @pcol=  
 STUFF(( 
  SELECT 
        DISTINCT N', Institution'+ CAST (ranking AS NVARCHAR(25)) +', '+  N'Intstatus'+ CAST (ranking AS NVARCHAR(25))
  FROM #temp
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SET @qu=N'SELECT refno, firmstatus,'+ @pcol +  
N' FROM 
    (
    select refno,firmstatus,ColData,colheader+ CAST(ranking as varchar) as colnames from 
    (select * from #temp)s
    UNPIVOT
    (ColData for colheader in ([institution], [intstatus])) up

    )S
  PIVOT
  (MAX(ColData) FOR colnames IN ('+@pcol +N')) AS piv'

EXEC sp_executesql @qu -- execute the dynamic sql
DROP TABLE #temp -- remove the temp table
```

The temp table in above script was created like below

```
--create table temp( refno nvarchar(20), firmstatus nvarchar(20), institution nvarchar(20), intstatus nvarchar(20))
--insert into temp  values 
--('AAA/1','Active','InstA','Ongoing'),
--('AAA/1','Active','InstB','Ongoing'),
--('AAA/1','Active','InstC','Ongoing'),
--('AAA/2','Active','InstA','Ongoing'),
--('AAA/2','Active','InstB','Ongoing')
```

Result received:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If repeated columns number is small and restricted, you can use simple solution:

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY refno, fmstatus ORDER BY institution) n
FROM myTable
),

B AS (
SELECT refno, fmstatus,
CASE WHEN n=1 THEN institution END institution,
CASE WHEN n=1 THEN intstatus END intstatus,
CASE WHEN n=2 THEN institution END institution1,
CASE WHEN n=2 THEN intstatus END intstatus1,
CASE WHEN n=3 THEN institution END institution2,
CASE WHEN n=3 THEN intstatus END intstatus2
FROM A
)

SELECT refno, fmstatus,
MAX(institution) institution,
MAX(intstatus) intstatus,
MAX(institution1) institution1,
MAX(intstatus1) intstatus1,
MAX(institution2) institution2,
MAX(intstatus2) intstatus2
FROM B
GROUP BY refno, fmstatus
```

Otherwise use PIVOT

Comment: There is a possibility that the result need more than 3 institution and intstatus columns.