# SQL Transposing columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

I'm attempting to transpose a column of text and values to row headers. I've researched the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` function but this function relies on aggregation from what I've gathered. Below is what I'm interested in achieving.

Source Table Schema:

```
    [ID]    [Category]  [TextName]
       1         A          u
       1         B          v
       1         C          w
       2         A          x
       2         B          y
       2         C          z
```

Resulting transpose:

```
[ID]    [A]   [B]   [C]
   1     u     v     w
   2     x     y     z
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? It makes a difference.

Comment: Also, even if the `pivot` and `unpivot` functions rely on aggregating, you might be able to use `min()` or `first()` as your aggregate functions. Not having numerical values doesn't necessarily mean you can't use those functions.

Comment: SQL Server...should have mentioned that. Thanks!

Comment: Please refer this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630650/pivot-with-varchar-datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       MIN( CASE WHEN Category = 'A' THEN TextName END ) AS A,
       MIN( CASE WHEN Category = 'B' THEN TextName END ) AS B,
       MIN( CASE WHEN Category = 'C' THEN TextName END ) AS C
  FROM Table
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is still a kind of aggregation even that we have a single value per cell (row-column combination).
Min/Max will give you the desired values since any basic type including strings have definition of Min/Max.

```
select  *
from    t pivot (min([TextName]) for [Category]  in (A,B,C)) p
```

---

```
+----+---+---+---+
| ID | A | B | C |
+----+---+---+---+
| 1  | u | v | w |
+----+---+---+---+
| 2  | x | y | z |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Comment: It worked for most of what I was looking for. However, in terms of performance, I found Teja's suggestion to be quicker. Additionally, I also needed a GROUP BY clause

Comment: 1. You've got better performance on your real data with GROUP BY?  2. Why do you need GROUP BY clause?